# How to determine the audio stream type by analising byte patterns

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

I've just started to build an iternet radio receiver application for android which works fine for .mp3 and .pls extension URLs.

I find that there are many streaming stations just given by IP address and port number (//101.102.103.104:8080 for example).

My question is,if I receive a large number of bytes from such URL, how can I determine the type of audio stream (is it wav or mp3 or pls or something else) , in order to apply a decoder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

File-name extension is meaningless in HTTP.  Sniffing content type from raw data is difficult, not always reliable, and inefficient.  The correct way to do this is to look at the `Content-Type` response header.  Here are the typical headers for a stream:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Expires:Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
icy-br:256
icy-genre:Drum and Bass Jungle
icy-name:Drum and Bass - Digitally Imported Premium
icy-notice1:<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-pub:0
icy-url:http://www.di.fm
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Icecast 2.3.3-kh7
```

The content type `audio/mpeg` indicates MP3 (or some other MPEG audio stream, but I only ever see MP3).  There are many others, such as `audio/aacp` or `audio/ogg`.